# Are there laptops for sale with elementary OS preinstalled

Tags: release-freya, ubuntu, laptop

I have seen a lot of laptops for sale running Ubuntu.I have never seen a laptops elementary OS preinstallated for sale.

Has anyone seen laptops preinstallated with elementary OS ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a small company in Spain that manufactures ultrabooks with elementary OS installed, but for now only distributed in this country.

More info [Slimbook.es](http://www.slimbook.es)

They have a video in their webpage showing a Slimbook booting in 12 seconds with elementary OS :

[Slimbook booting](https://youtu.be/149xKxdcNIQ)

Comment: It looks very promising!

Comment: Does the laptop have a SSD. I would really like to have my freya boot like that.Also are these only available in Spain

Comment: Yes,  the quick booting is due to a ssd.

Comment: So are they only in Spain. I see lots of Ubuntu laptops from different brands for sale in my country

Comment: @bitseater Does the Windows key have an elementary logo. Also where can I buy elementary stickers for my Windows key

Comment: @Suico Doga,  you can buy them at http://www.unixstickers.com/stickers/linux-keyboard-stickers/elementary-os-square-keybaord-stickers-cover-windows-flag#intro

Answer (score 2):

In Germany there is a shop [Tuxedo](http://www.tuxedocomputers.com). They offer Linux-specialised hardware. While configuring your new system you can choose elementary OS as pre-installed OS. Other OS's are also Ubuntu-based.

I do not know if they ship international, so have a look at their website.